# Ionic Jasmine : env.stopOnSpecFailure is not a function after compiled successfully

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Using Ionic with jasmine-karma, while run test, getting success compile but in jasmine dashboard getting empty screen with error in console.

Following tutorial : https://leifwells.github.io/2017/08/27/testing-in-ionic-configure-existing-projects-for-testing/

```
"ts-loader": "^4.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.99.1"
```

Error Messages :

```
TypeError: env.stopOnSpecFailure is not a function at adapter.js:26

Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterCompile' of undefined
```

Answer (score 18):

The failure occurs in your version of karma-jasmine which tries to use the stopOnSpecFailure function. That function is not present in your version of jasmine-core, you'll need version 3 or greater. Version 3.1.0 is the newest right now and works good. Also note that if you're using Webpack 3 you should also [downgrade ts-loader to 3.5.0](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that many people suggests downgrading jasmine-core to 2.99.1. Apparently people have problems using jasmine-core 3. If that's the case for you, then you can use [karma-jasmine-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter?activeTab=readme) version 0.2.2 together with jasmine-core 2.99.1.

Comment: yes, specifically when upgrading karma to a version that works with Angular 5, if you upgrade jasmine-core beyond 2.99.0 you get the error `HeadlessChrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR` (which I am still getting even though I'm using jasmine-core 2.99.0)

Comment: I had the environment.hideDisabled is not a function error (https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1523) then downgraded to jasmine-core: 2.99.1 and got the stopOnSpecFailure. I upgraded jasmine-core to latest version 3.2.1 and also karma-jasmine-html-reporter to 1.3.1 and now its fine.

Comment: I upgraded my dependencies as suggested by Tallerlei and it worked for me.