# Karma Jasmine Html report is not showing up on ng test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm not able to get karma jasmine Html report when running unit testing in chrome. Chrome is loading with component's html but not showing test results.

However i'm getting test results in terminal itself. I've tried adding below in karma.config.js but getting errors.

In Pulgins --> require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
In reporters --> kjhtml

{

```
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: env.stopOnSpecFailure is not a function\nat node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:26:7\n\nTypeError: env.stopOnSpecFailure is not a function\n    at node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:26:7\n    at node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:76:3",

"str": "Uncaught TypeError: env.stopOnSpecFailure is not a function\nat node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:26:7\n\nTypeError: env.stopOnSpecFailure is not a function\n    at node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:26:7\n    at node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter/src/lib/adapter.js:76:3"
```

}

Below are the versions in package.json

```
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
```

Below is the Karma.config.js

// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      captureConsole: false
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'reports/junit/',
      outputFile: 'TESTS-xunit.xml',
      useBrowserName: false,
      suite: '' // Will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      dir: './reports/coverage',
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    // Level of logging, can be: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you post your karma.config.js file?

Comment: Thanks @BillTurner, I've posted karma.config.js in my question.

Comment: Reading through another issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449082/ionic-jasmine-env-stoponspecfailure-is-not-a-function-after-compiled-successfu) there are issues with the newer karma-jasmine.  You've got the versions recommended, except for karma-jasmine-html-reporter, recommend using 0.2.2.  My setup is almost the same as yours except for that, and it's working OK.

Comment: Hi @BillTurner, Still getting same error after updating it to 0.2.2.